# is there a way to update an entity using nodejs library of dialogflow es?

Tags: javascript, node.js, dialogflow-es, gcloud

I have been trying to update a entity in Dialogflow es using the nodejs SDK, but I haven't been able to do it, the API reference does not give enough information so I need help with.

the name of the entity I want add a new value its @Productos

So far this has been de the code I have been trying to implement.

```js
 updateEntity:async (req, res) => {
    try{
      const projectAgentPath = entityClient.projectAgentPath(clientId)   /// (clientId);
      console.log('whats projectAgentPaht',projectAgentPath);
      const request = {
        parent: projectAgentPath,
        
        
        
      }


      const response  = await entityClient.updateEntityType({
        
        entityType: {
          name: '@Productos',
          displayName: "Productos",
          entities: [
            {value: 'Nuevo producto'}
          ]

        },
      
      });
     // const response = entityClient.getEntityType(request)
      /*const [response] = await intentsClient.listIntents(request);*/
      console.log('whats response ', response);
      return res.json(response).status(200)  

    }catch(e){
      console.log('e ', e)
     return res.json({message: 'ocurrio un problema al procesar la solictud'}).status(500);
    }
```

the code above gives the following error

```sh
 projectAgentPaht projects/prod-proinvestec/agent
e  Error: 3 INVALID_ARGUMENT: Resource name '@Productos' does not match 'projects/*/locations/*/agent/entityTypes/*'.
    at Object.callErrorFromStatus (D:\Projects\iqbit\chatbot-server\node_modules\@grpc\grpc-js\build\src\call.js:31:26)
    at Object.onReceiveStatus (D:\Projects\iqbit\chatbot-server\node_modules\@grpc\grpc-js\build\src\client.js:189:52)
    at Object.onReceiveStatus (D:\Projects\iqbit\chatbot-server\node_modules\@grpc\grpc-js\build\src\client-interceptors.js:365:141)
    at Object.onReceiveStatus (D:\Projects\iqbit\chatbot-server\node_modules\@grpc\grpc-js\build\src\client-interceptors.js:328:181)
    at D:\Projects\iqbit\chatbot-server\node_modules\@grpc\grpc-js\build\src\call-stream.js:187:78
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:78:11) {
  code: 3,
  details: "Resource name '@Productos' does not match 'projects/*/locations/*/agent/entityTypes/*'.",
  metadata: Metadata {
    internalRepr: Map(1) { 'grpc-server-stats-bin' => [Array] },
    options: {}
  },
  note: 'Exception occurred in retry method that was not classified as transient'
```

I want to add new values to the products entity.
I hope someone could help me.
Thanks!

Comment: Did you try my posted answer? If you find it helpful, you may upvote/accept it so that way others know that you've been (sufficiently) helped.

Comment: Hello @ScottB, I haven't tried your solution but I used another solution, the thing was that I needed to add new products names to the product entity, but this names have a pattern so I used regex. Thank you for your time and your answer, I will keep this as a option in a near future.

Comment: You may post your alternative solution and accept it for the benefit of the community that may encounter the same use case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just used regex to detect the name of the products instead of adding values to the products entity.

lol

Answer (score 0):

You first need to get the **resource name** of your specific `entityType` that you want to update. You may use below `cURL` command for getting the **resource name**.

```
curl -X GET \
-H "Authorization: Bearer "$(gcloud auth application-default print-access-token) \
-H "Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8" \
"https://dialogflow.googleapis.com/v2/projects/<your-project-id>/agent/entityTypes"
```

Below is a sample screenshot where to find the resource name on the result of the `cURL` command.
[image]

You may now use the updated code below (derived from your posted code) in which we use the **resource name** on the *"name"* parameter and we added the *"kind"* parameter since this is required when using the `updateEntityType()` function.

```js
const dialogflow = require('@google-cloud/dialogflow');

const entityClient = new dialogflow.EntityTypesClient();

async function main() {
    
    const projectAgentPath = entityClient.projectAgentPath('your-project-id') 
      console.log('whats projectAgentPath',projectAgentPath);
      const request = {
        parent: projectAgentPath,
        
        }


      const response  = await entityClient.updateEntityType({
        
        entityType: {
          name: "projects/<your-project-id>/agent/entityTypes/<entity-type-id>",
          displayName: "Productos",
          kind: 'KIND_MAP',
          entities: [
            {value: 'Nuevo producto'}
          ]

        },
      
      });
     // const response = entityClient.getEntityType(request)
      /*const [response] = await intentsClient.listIntents(request);*/
      console.log('whats response ', response);
  }
  
  process.on('unhandledRejection', err => {
    console.error(err.message);
    process.exitCode = 1;
  });
  main(...process.argv.slice(2));
```